# PHP & MySQL Input String Escape Problem

Tags: php, mysql, string

I've a weird string escape problem with my PHP script. I'm trying to get data from iSnare and put them into MySQL table.

I'm reading POST data and escaping strings with mysql_real_espace_string() function, also I can insert same data to .txt file without a problem but when I try to insert data into table, it cuts the string from apostrophes (') (or another char sometimes)

If that helps, my tables and fields are UTF8 and utf8_general_ci..

```
include("database.php");

 function security_sql($x){
    return mysql_real_escape_string(trim(stripslashes($x)));
 }

$title = security_sql($_POST["article_title"]);
$first_name = security_sql($_POST["article_author"]);
$description = security_sql($_POST["article_summary"]);
$category = security_sql($_POST["article_category"]);
$article = security_sql($_POST["article_body_text"]);
$article_html = security_sql($_POST["article_body_html"]);
$resource_box = security_sql($_POST["article_bio_text"]);
$resource_box_html = security_sql($_POST["article_bio_html"]);
$keywords = security_sql($_POST["article_keywords"]);
$email = security_sql($_POST["article_email"]);


// Writes fine to text file
$fp = fopen('test.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $title."\n");
fwrite($fp, $article."\n\n\n\n");
fclose($fp);



// BUT DOESNT WORK FINE WITH MYSQL
mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles (first_name, email, title, description, article, article_html, category, resource_box, resource_box_html, keywords, distributor, distributor_host) values (
                                                 '".$first_name."',
                                                 '".$email."',
                                                 '".$title."',
                                                 '".$description."',
                                                 '".$article."',
                                                 '".$article_html."',
                                                 '".$category."',
                                                 '".$resource_box."',
                                                 '".$resource_box_html."',
                                                 '".$keywords."',
                                                 'isnare',
                                                 '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."'
                                                 )") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Why are you calling stripslashes() before escaping the string?  Although that wouldn't cause the particular behavior you've described, it would end up storing incorrect values (something that came in as `\'` would end up getting stored as `'` instead).  (Unless the dreaded Magic Quotes setting is on, in which case the stripslashes() call makes sense.)

Comment: "magic_quotes_gpc" is "On" in PHP, so I'm doing stripslashes() before mysql_real_escape_string() as it recommended in PHP manual. (but also I thought same thing and tried without stripslashes() too, doesn't work either)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd reccomend using htmlentities with the ENT_QUOTES flag as a part of your own sanitizing function.

```
function clean($string) {
    $ret = str_replace('=','&#61;',$string);
    $ret = htmlentities($ret,ENT_QUOTES);
    return $ret;
    }
```

Above is the very simple sanitizing function I use for content output to a web browser stored in a relational database. It's probably not perfect, but it works well for me. (Note, = must be replaced to prevent injected queries involving integers)